# php - get text having no class or tags html dom parser

Tags: php, web-scraping, domparser

I have stucked in a typical case.. I need some text from the table which have no class nor any tag.. this is just a plain text.. I want to get this text only . I need to scrape **I WANT THIS TEXT**.  How will I do that

MY HTML

```
<td class="example">
  <strong>text in strong</strong><br>
  <strong>2nd text in strong:</strong> 

       I WANT THIS TEXT
  <br> 

  <strong><span style="color:red;">another text</span></strong>
  <br> 
  <a href="#" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
</td>
```

**I have tried so far :** 
as we have to scrape multiple lines, I am using **foreach** loop

```
 foreach($html->find('td.example') as $element){

        echo $element->find('strong', 1)->outertext . "<br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your html string is in the variable $html, then the following regular expression should work:

```
/** Replace the carriage return with '^' */
$html = str_replace("\r", "^", $html);
/** Replace the line feed with '~' */
$html = str_replace("\n", "~", $html);

/** regular expression is used to match the text */
preg_match("/<strong>.*<\/strong><br>.*<strong>.*<\/strong>(.+)<br><strong><span style="color:red;">.*<\/span><\/strong>/iU", $html, $matches);

/** The '^' is replaced with '\r' */
$matches[1]  = str_replace("^", '\r', $matches[1]);

/** The '~' is replaced with '\n' */
$text        = str_replace("~", '\n', $matches[1]);
```

The variable $text contains the matches text